# TypeScript: typeguarding enums

Tags: typescript

I am trying to validate that a string is the value of an enum, but the compiler keeps throwing an error and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is an example code

```
enum A {
  a = 'a'
}

const isStringAnEnum = <T>(enumObject: T, fieldValue: unknown): fieldValue is T => {
  return Object.values(enumObject).includes(fieldValue);
};

const logEnum = (enumToLog: A) => console.log(enumToLog);

const exec = () => {
  const str = 'a' as unknown;

  if (isValueWithinEnum(A, str)) {
    logEnum(str);
  }
};

exec();
```

and here is an error I get at the line where I pass str to logEnum

```
Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'.ts(2345)
```

Thank you

Comment: When you just use `A` and not a member of `A` like `A.a`, it's of type `typeof A`, not `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<T>(enumObject: T, fieldValue: unknown): fieldValue is T
```

Since `T` is the enum object, this return type means that fieldValue will be the entire enum object, not a member of that object. Instead do:

```
<T>(enumObject: T, fieldValue: unknown): fieldValue is T[keyof T]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKUCGUC8UDkruIF9FEBjAexAGcAXKAS0oDVUAbMYAdTuoAs6QAouGhYAPABUAfAApQkAPIAjAFbAS1AFxRxAGigAzOsBYATZm2BawIANYgyAdxABKLYeNnW7epW0BtG2AATzJ9bQBdTEkEZCgAJ2BqMDiQKCVVdQA6ADcvYEpZYXS1amdM-hI2E3zpd1NzdmcAbkIW0goaKBYyAHMhSEwoQshxMgAZXq0YZyiocioyFmBM7p7hiFGJnubiec7gAA81QekZjGikFD3aGjjB3Gw0X2s7RxA2lDow6QYGzm4%20IJhNIYHpbs4ZpcUF1ev0INJwS0UEQCE0gA)

Comment: playground link is broken